# To hide the default hover css from link

Tags: javascript, css, jointjs

I am using following code to add links to the graph:

```
var ln = new joint.dia.Link({
    source: { id: rect.id }, target: { id: curr_selected.id },
     attrs: { '.marker-source': { d: 'M 10 0 L 0 5 L 10 10 z' } }
});
```

Now when I added this link to graph. A cross symbol for delete operation comes by default on hovering the link but I do not want it. I need a simple arrow which can not be deleted by anyone from the graph.

Answer (score 1):

You can just set the following in your CSS:

```
.link-tools {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: It works but I need it for a specific links not for all the links inside the paper .how should I do for a specific link?

Comment: You can add a class to the link view container and then reference it in CSS specifically for that link: `V(paper.findViewByModel(ln).el).addClass('special-link')` and then in CSS: `.special-link .link-tools { display: none }`